# XML Data Image Binding for thumbnail Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to create a thumbnail gallery using XML databinding. But the data is not binding. Here is the one which I am trying.

http://jsfiddle.net/5wETg/

Here I want to show all the three images that are in my XML using only one image tag which I used in my HTML.

Comment: You can't have 3 images in one image tag

Comment: @Musa: Is there any alternate solution, because we need to update every time if the images are getting increased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `<img>` tag for each image, I use `.map()` to create a jQuery object containg all the images and then append them to `#thumbs`

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'>\
    <channel>\
    <image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image>\
    <image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image>\
    <image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image>\
    </channel>\
    </rss>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$image= $xml.find( "image" );

$( "#thumbs" ).append( $image.map(function(){
        return $('<img>', {className: 'thumbnails', src:$(this).text()})[0];
    })
);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5wETg/21/)

http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use this one?

```
<div id="thumbs"></div>
```

script:

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image><image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image><image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image>    </channel></rss>",

    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $image= $xml.find( "image" );



$($image).each(function(index, element) {
    $( "<img />" ).attr('src', $(element).text()).appendTo('#thumbs');
});​
```